# Using counter as condition

Tags: python, collections, counter

I'm trying to do a condition based the number of appearances of the variables.
If any variable appears more than once it will appear as wrong if each variable appears once it will only appear as right. I tried this but didn´t work:

```
from collections import Counter
z = ['blue', 'red', 'yellow']
Counter(z)
print(Counter(z))

if Counter(z).items() != 1:
    print('Wrong')
else:
    print('Right')
```

Comment: 1) Every time you call Counter(z) you're creating a new Counter object. 2) .items() doesn't do what you think it does (look up the documentation for Counter and python dicts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `all` for checking single occurrence condition.
If `value` is 1 then it will append `True` into the list else `False`

`all` checks if all the elements in the list are `True`,

```
from collections import Counter
z = ['blue', 'red', 'red','yellow']
dic = Counter(z)

if all(value == 1 for key, value in dic.items()):
    print('Right')
else:
    print('Wrong')
```

Comment: There is no list, and nothing is being appended to anything. `all` does not create a list, it simply iterates the iterable it receives (in this case a generator) and short-circuits when the predicate is `False` for the first time

Comment: Please, an example when the predicate is `False` for the first time?

Comment: @DeepSpace , yes you are correct my bad, it will be an iterable not a list.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to achieve this will be to use `all` over `counter.values()` (which holds all the counts):

```
from collections import Counter

right_counter = Counter([1, 2])

if all(count == 1 for count in right_counter.values()):
    print('right')
else:
    print('wrong')

wrong_counter = Counter([1, 1, 2])

if all(count == 1 for count in wrong_counter.values()):
    print('right')
else:
    print('wrong')
```

outputs

```
right
wrong
```

Alternatively, you can make sure the length of the list equals to the length of the set of the list:

```
right_list = [1, 2]
wrong_list = [1, 1, 2]

if len(right_list) == len(set(right_list)):
    print('right')
else:
    print('wrong')

if len(wrong_list) == len(set(wrong_list)):
    print('right')
else:
    print('wrong')
```

also outputs

```
right
wrong
```